# retrieved html and php code from database is not updating

Tags: php, html, mysql

i created a menu which have HTML and PHP code, and I insert both code to database, retrieve the code from database using php and display it through [code mirror](http://codemirror.net/), but when I try to update my HTML and PHP code, retrieved from database, it's not updating, its remain as it before and then I removed PHP code from the code and the code now contains HTML only, after that the updating is happend normally. I have to use PHP with HTML, please suggest me any ideas or solution to overcome this, i am not sure what make this wrong. Advance thanx to all.

> this is my HTML and PHP code

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>PRODUCT</h3>
  <div>
   <a 
   href="electrical_equipments.php" 
   class="<?php if($basename == $accor_data['p_c_page']){ echo $acco_active; } ?>"
   >
   ELECTRICAL EQUIPMENTS
   </a>
   <a 
   href="power_engineering.php" 
   class="<?php if($basename == $acco_data['p_c_page']){ echo $acco_active; } ?>"
   >
   POWER ENGINEERING
   </a>
   <a 
   href="hvac_air_conditioning.php" 
   class="<?php if($basename == $acco_data['p_c_page']){ echo $acco_active; } ?>"
   >
   HVAC AIR CONDITIONING
   </a>
</div>
```

> this is my code to update above HTML & PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['yes_confirm']))
{
 include "connection.php";
 $text_update = "UPDATE page_menu SET p_m_text = '".$_POST['p_m_text']."' WHERE p_m_group = 'accordion'";
 $text_query = mysql_query($text_update);
 mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: You appreciate that this is an accident just waiting to happen?

Comment: Using prepared statements should fix your problem (cause of your `'` in the PHP code). And don't use the `mysql` extension cause its deprecated and gets removed in one of the next PHP versions. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: many thanx to TiMESPLiNTER for your answer and suggestion. its worked.